# Custom user model permissions

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

So everything works fine, but I can't add permissions to my users through admin.
When I change an user the box with User permissions appears in place but all the permissions I add have no effect. When I log in as that user I don't have permission to do anything.

[image: When I try to change an user]

This is what I have in "accounts.models":

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.http import urlquote

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    now = timezone.now()

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

    email= self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
            date_joined=now, **extra_fields
        )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'))
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name=_('user')
        verbose_name_plural = ('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.email)
    def get_full_name(self):
       return self.username
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

This is what I have in "accounts.admin":

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from .models import CustomUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'is_active') 
    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'last_login', 'date_joined')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_active')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'is_active')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email', 'username')
    ordering = ('email',)

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
# admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please check at your db , whether your UserID is mapped with "auth_user_groups" table.

For example:

id: 2155
user_id: 2447276
group_id: 45

Comment: I am not really sure how to do that, I added an image with the tables, I am using postgresql